# If statement in Flask using string variable from SQL database

Tags: python, mysql

I'm creating a program where I need to check if a certain cell in a table equals a string value and, if it does not, to **not** change that value. Here is some snippet of the code for clarification:

```
if (db.execute("SELECT :rowchosen FROM userboard WHERE column=:columnchosen", rowchosen = rowchosen, columnchosen = columnchosen)) == '-'):
    #change value of cell
else:
    #go to a new page that displays an error
```

Yet, whenever I run this code, I always get an error because the value (I believe) prints as a dictionary value, something like {"row" = 'row'} of that sort. Any help/advice as to why this happens?

Comment: which db are you using? can you tell what the db.execute method is doing? are you querying sqllite?

Comment: The DB name is "userboard". The db.execute method grabs the command from the SQL database, and yes, I am querying SQLlite.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure that `userboard` is the database and not the table?

i think, here is what you want to do

```
conn = sqlite3.connect(db_file)
cur = conn.cursor()
cur.execute("SELECT * FROM userboard WHERE one=?", (columnchosen,))

rows = cur.fetchall()

for row in rows:
    print(row)
```

now, in the loop `for row in rows:` you need to perform your check. For all the rows returned, you need to check each row for `-` in the appropriate column

also check out http://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-python/sqlite-python-select/

Comment: Thanks for this! I did this code similarly, and instead get an array of the values in a specific row.The variable dictating the process is the row value (in a column called "letters") and then the column names themselves are numbers... sorry for being confusing.

Comment: no worries. can you post what a row looks like and which column the `-` value should be in?

Comment: Sure. A row looks like this:
('B', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-'), and the "Letter" value should be B and the "number" value should be 'one'. So the datatbale is a series of columns, the first named 'Letters' the second named 'one' the third named 'two' etc etc

Comment: good, so from this row, which value do you want to change? in other words, which column number do you want to check for `-` value

Comment: Column name is 'one'.

Comment: cool, so checkout the updated query in my answer. this should give you all rows where `one=-`